# Solve the following algebraic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Questions:**
a) Show that $$(\sqrt{2} + 1)^2 = 3+2\sqrt2$$

b) Express $$\cos3\theta$$in the form of$$\cos\theta(a-b\sin^2\theta)$$

c) Solve $$\sqrt2(\sin2\theta+\cos\theta) + \cos3\theta = \sin2\theta + \cos2\theta$$ $$\Theta \in [0,360]$$

**Answers:**
a) $$(\sqrt{2} + 1)^2 = 2 + 1 + 2\sqrt2 = 3+2\sqrt2$$

b) 
\begin{align*}
\cos3\theta &= \cos(2\theta + \theta)\\
&=\cos2\theta\cos\theta - \sin2\theta\sin\theta\\
&=(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)(\cos\theta) -2\sin\theta\cos\theta\sin\theta\\
&=\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta-2\sin^2\theta)\\
&=\cos\theta(1-4\sin^2\theta)
\end{align*}

c) I'm still working on this one, this was my approach
\begin{align*}
\sqrt2(\sin2\theta+\cos\theta)+\cos3\theta &= \sin2\theta + \cos2\theta\\
\implies\sqrt2(2\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos\theta)+\cos\theta(1-4\sin^2\theta)&= 2\sin\theta\cos\theta + 1 -2\sin^2\theta\\
\sqrt2\cos\theta(2\sin\theta + 1)+\cos\theta(1-4\sin^2\theta) &= 2\sin\theta\cos\theta + 2\cos^2\theta - 1
\end{align*}

Before I proceed further, I would like to know whether this would be the right approach. Also, any tips on my formatting would be a great help. I need help with spacing the equations.

Comment: To me it seems okay.

Comment: Is "$\cos3\theta$ in the form of $\cos\theta(a-b\sin\theta)$"correct? You got "$=\cos\theta(1-4\sin^2\theta)$" where  we have a square.

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry, I have made a mistake in the question, I shall edit it.

Comment: For the formatting, use `\begin{align*} [LaTeX here, with lines separated by \\\ and & placed where you want to line things up]\end{align*}`  

For example, `\begin{align*}a &= b \\&= c\end{align*}` produces: 

\begin{align*}a &= b \\&= c\end{align*}

Comment: @user3482749 Thanks!

Comment: Write $t=\sin \theta$ then $\cos \theta = \sqrt{1-t^2}$. Now your equation is purely algebric in terms of $t$